# Why it is impossible to replace tokens in Azure DevOps CI?

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops, yaml, continuous-integration

I have issue with replacing tokens using the plugin (Replace Tokens) in Azure Devops. I have json file in my project, but I don't want to store credentials there. Due to this I've created variables in Azure Pipelines Library and want to parse credentials from there directly during CI. Please see below part from yml file.

```
- task: replacetokens@3
  displayName: 'Replace tokens'
  inputs:
    targetFiles: |
      **/config.json
    tokenPrefix: '$('
    tokenSuffix: ')'
```

Below my json file:

```
{
  "number": "$(number)"
}
```

And I am adding screenshot from Azure Pipelines Library where the credentials stored
[azure pipelines library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vnqe4.jpg)

P.S. I am not sure if my issue depend on the programming language or not, I guess not, but anyway please note that I am using Python and this is the simple part of code where I am trying to use variable which I defined in azure Pipelines Library:

```
import json

f = open('config.json')
data = json.load(f)

number_variable = data['number']
print(number_variable)
```

Here is the CI answer to me:

```
##[warning]  variable not found: number
 0 token(s) replaced out of 1
replaced 0 tokens out of 1 in 1 file(s) in 0.1 seconds.
```

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE:**

I assume that issue related to the fact that variables in Azure Pipelines Library is not visible to yml file. So, I changed yml file like below but it is still not working.

```
variables:
  group: $(credgroup)
steps:

- task: replacetokens@3
  displayName: 'Replace tokens'
  inputs:
    targetFiles: |
      **/config.json
    tokenPrefix: '$('
    tokenSuffix: ')'
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Here I am adding the screen of my variable group. [variable group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKuT2.jpg)

Comment: The `replacetokens` plugins finds the token, but not a value for it. When you reference the variable group you do that through a variable `$(credgroup)`. What is the value of `credgroup`? Please see the docs for how to reference a variable group: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups

Comment: credgroup is the name of group in Azure Pipeline Library and the credentials like username, password etc stored inside it

Comment: Where do you define the variable called `credgroup`? Does it wok if you specify the nae of the variable group directly instead of through a variable?

Comment: How can I do it like that? As far as I know it is required to replace tokens one by one..

Answer (score 0):

From your YAML sample, there is a problem with the syntax you are using to call the Variable Group. In this case, it will not able to use the variable in variable group.

```
variables:
  group: $(credgroup)
```

You can try to use the following format to call the Variable Group.

```
variables:
  - group: variablegroupname
```

Refer to this doc: [variables.group definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/variables-group?view=azure-pipelines)

Comment: Hi. Thanks for answer. Do I need to specify the name of group of variables directly or by using $() syntax?

Comment: You can directly define the variable group name in YAML sample.

Comment: But I have the name pf group in Azure Library. My variable group is not defined directly in pipelines. I have create them in advance and store them inside Azure Pipeline Library.

Comment: Variable group are used to save pipeline variables. Why you are saving the variable group name in Azure Pipeline Library? The variable group should have the name and then you can use it in Pipeline.

Comment: Hi. Could you please check the my last update above. I have added the screen. I am not sure that we are correctly understanding each other. So what I am actually doing. I've created group of variables with the group name "credgroup" inside this group I've added the variables like password which is the real one. In my code I already have the json file, but inside the json file I am not storing the real password.

Comment: So, in order to replace the $(password) from json file to the real one from credgroup I've wrote the yml file and called credgroup there in order to be able to replace the password which is the real on and this variable already included to the credgroup. That is why I am calling credgroup in yml. But anyway if I am not ading credgroup to yml the result is the same and it is not possible to replace tokens. So the main probem is that the yml file is not aware about Azure Library at all.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `tokenPattern: 'custom'`.

> **Token pattern** (tokenPattern): specify the pattern of the tokens to search in the target files. Default is `default` (allowed values: `default`, `rm`, `octopus`, `azpipelines`, `doublebraces` and `custom`)

Source: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens